# AUTO_BACKUP not even trying to backup database

Tags: db2

I've setup 2 identical linux servers with db2 10.5 . `AUTO_BACKUP` only works on one of them. Also, no health notifications come from that server at all, although `postfix` on `localhost` is running and a test message with `sendmail` is delivered.

The missing message I expect to see in `db2diag` :

```
Automatic job "Backup database online" has started on database STAGE_DB, alias STAGE_DB
```

I have:

- `HEALTH_MON, AUTO_MAINT, AUTO_DB_BACKUP` are all `ON`
- backup criteria - do if older than 1 day
- Online window is 24/7
- `db2dasrrm` aka DAS is running

what else?

Window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DB2MaintenanceWindows 
xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/db2/autonomic/config" >

 <!-- Online Maintenance Window  -->
 <OnlineWindow Occurrence="During" startTime="00:00:00" duration="24" >
  <DaysOfWeek>All</DaysOfWeek>
  <DaysOfMonth>All</DaysOfMonth>
  <MonthsOfYear>All</MonthsOfYear>
 </OnlineWindow>
</DB2MaintenanceWindows>
```

backup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<DB2AutoBackupPolicy 
xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/db2/autonomic/config" >

 <!--   Backup Options  -->
 <BackupOptions mode="Online"> 
  <BackupTarget>
  <DiskBackupTarget>
    <PathName>/media/okbackup/rsnapshot/hourly.0/ec-stage-db-1/db2autobak/STAGE_DB/</PathName>
  </DiskBackupTarget>
  </BackupTarget>
 </BackupOptions>

 <!--  Frequency of automatic backups -->

 <BackupCriteria numberOfFullBackups="1" timeSinceLastBackup="24" logSpaceConsumedSinceLastBackup="1000000"/>

</DB2AutoBackupPolicy>
```

admin.cfg:

```
            Admin Server Configuration

 Authentication Type DAS                (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER_ENCRYPT

 DAS Administration Authority Group Name  (DASADM_GROUP) = dasadm1

 DAS Discovery Mode                           (DISCOVER) = SEARCH
 Name of the DB2 Server System               (DB2SYSTEM) = EC-STAGE-DB-1

 Java Development Kit Installation Path DAS   (JDK_PATH) = AUTOMATIC (/home/dasusr1/das/java/jdk)
 Java Development Kit Installation Path DAS   (JDK_64_PATH) = AUTOMATIC (/home/dasusr1/das/java/jdk)

 DAS Code Page                            (DAS_CODEPAGE) = 0
 DAS Territory                           (DAS_TERRITORY) = 0

 Location of Contact List                 (CONTACT_HOST) = 
 Execute Expired Tasks                   (EXEC_EXP_TASK) = NO
 Scheduler Mode                           (SCHED_ENABLE) = OFF
 SMTP Server                               (SMTP_SERVER) = localhost
 Tools Catalog Database                    (TOOLSCAT_DB) = 
 Tools Catalog Database Instance         (TOOLSCAT_INST) = 
 Tools Catalog Database Schema         (TOOLSCAT_SCHEMA) = 
 Scheduler User ID                                       = 

 Diagnostic error capture level              (DIAGLEVEL) = 3
```

dbm.cfg:

```
          Database Manager Configuration

     Node type = Enterprise Server Edition with local and remote clients

 Database manager configuration release level            = 0x1000

 CPU speed (millisec/instruction)             (CPUSPEED) = 2.597893e-07
 Communications bandwidth (MB/sec)      (COMM_BANDWIDTH) = 1.000000e+02

 Max number of concurrently active databases     (NUMDB) = 32
 Federated Database System Support           (FEDERATED) = NO
 Transaction processor monitor name        (TP_MON_NAME) = 

 Default charge-back account           (DFT_ACCOUNT_STR) = 

 Java Development Kit installation path       (JDK_PATH) = /home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/jdk64

 Diagnostic error capture level              (DIAGLEVEL) = 3
 Notify Level                              (NOTIFYLEVEL) = 3
 Diagnostic data directory path               (DIAGPATH) = /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/
 Current member resolved DIAGPATH                        = /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/
 Alternate diagnostic data directory path (ALT_DIAGPATH) = 
 Current member resolved ALT_DIAGPATH                    = 
 Size of rotating db2diag & notify logs (MB)  (DIAGSIZE) = 100

 Default database monitor switches
   Buffer pool                         (DFT_MON_BUFPOOL) = OFF
   Lock                                   (DFT_MON_LOCK) = OFF
   Sort                                   (DFT_MON_SORT) = OFF
   Statement                              (DFT_MON_STMT) = OFF
   Table                                 (DFT_MON_TABLE) = OFF
   Timestamp                         (DFT_MON_TIMESTAMP) = ON
   Unit of work                            (DFT_MON_UOW) = OFF
 Monitor health of instance and databases   (HEALTH_MON) = ON

 SYSADM group name                        (SYSADM_GROUP) = DB2IADM1
 SYSCTRL group name                      (SYSCTRL_GROUP) = 
 SYSMAINT group name                    (SYSMAINT_GROUP) = 
 SYSMON group name                        (SYSMON_GROUP) = 

 Client Userid-Password Plugin          (CLNT_PW_PLUGIN) = 
 Client Kerberos Plugin                (CLNT_KRB_PLUGIN) = 
 Group Plugin                             (GROUP_PLUGIN) = 
 GSS Plugin for Local Authorization    (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) = 
 Server Plugin Mode                    (SRV_PLUGIN_MODE) = UNFENCED
 Server List of GSS Plugins      (SRVCON_GSSPLUGIN_LIST) = 
 Server Userid-Password Plugin        (SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN) = 
 Server Connection Authentication          (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED
 Cluster manager                                         = 

 Database manager authentication        (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER
 Alternate authentication           (ALTERNATE_AUTH_ENC) = NOT_SPECIFIED
 Cataloging allowed without authority   (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = NO
 Trust all clients                      (TRUST_ALLCLNTS) = YES
 Trusted client authentication          (TRUST_CLNTAUTH) = CLIENT
 Bypass federated authentication            (FED_NOAUTH) = NO

 Default database path                       (DFTDBPATH) = /home/db2inst1

 Database monitor heap size (4KB)          (MON_HEAP_SZ) = AUTOMATIC(90)
 Java Virtual Machine heap size (4KB)     (JAVA_HEAP_SZ) = 2048
 Audit buffer size (4KB)                  (AUDIT_BUF_SZ) = 0
 Global instance memory (4KB)          (INSTANCE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(1696865)
 Member instance memory (4KB)                            = GLOBAL
 Agent stack size                       (AGENT_STACK_SZ) = 1024
 Sort heap threshold (4KB)                  (SHEAPTHRES) = 0

 Directory cache support                     (DIR_CACHE) = YES

 Application support layer heap size (4KB)   (ASLHEAPSZ) = 15
 Max requester I/O block size (bytes)         (RQRIOBLK) = 65535
 Workload impact by throttled utilities(UTIL_IMPACT_LIM) = 10

 Priority of agents                           (AGENTPRI) = SYSTEM
 Agent pool size                        (NUM_POOLAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(100)
 Initial number of agents in pool       (NUM_INITAGENTS) = 0
 Max number of coordinating agents     (MAX_COORDAGENTS) = AUTOMATIC(200)
 Max number of client connections      (MAX_CONNECTIONS) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)

 Keep fenced process                        (KEEPFENCED) = YES
 Number of pooled fenced processes         (FENCED_POOL) = AUTOMATIC(MAX_COORDAGENTS)
 Initial number of fenced processes     (NUM_INITFENCED) = 0

 Index re-creation time and redo index build  (INDEXREC) = RESTART

 Transaction manager database name         (TM_DATABASE) = 1ST_CONN
 Transaction resync interval (sec)     (RESYNC_INTERVAL) = 180

 SPM name                                     (SPM_NAME) = ec_stage
 SPM log size                          (SPM_LOG_FILE_SZ) = 256
 SPM resync agent limit                 (SPM_MAX_RESYNC) = 20
 SPM log path                             (SPM_LOG_PATH) = 

 TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = 50000
 Discovery mode                               (DISCOVER) = SEARCH
 Discover server instance                (DISCOVER_INST) = ENABLE

 SSL server keydb file                   (SSL_SVR_KEYDB) = 
 SSL server stash file                   (SSL_SVR_STASH) = 
 SSL server certificate label            (SSL_SVR_LABEL) = 
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) = 
 SSL cipher specs                      (SSL_CIPHERSPECS) = 
 SSL versions                             (SSL_VERSIONS) = 
 SSL client keydb file                  (SSL_CLNT_KEYDB) = 
 SSL client stash file                  (SSL_CLNT_STASH) = 

 Maximum query degree of parallelism   (MAX_QUERYDEGREE) = ANY
 Enable intra-partition parallelism     (INTRA_PARALLEL) = NO

 Maximum Asynchronous TQs per query    (FEDERATED_ASYNC) = 0

 No. of int. communication buffers(4KB)(FCM_NUM_BUFFERS) = AUTOMATIC(4096)
 No. of int. communication channels   (FCM_NUM_CHANNELS) = AUTOMATIC(2048)
 Inter-node comm. parallelism          (FCM_PARALLELISM) = 1
 Node connection elapse time (sec)         (CONN_ELAPSE) = 10
 Max number of node connection retries (MAX_CONNRETRIES) = 5
 Max time difference between nodes (min) (MAX_TIME_DIFF) = 60

 db2start/db2stop timeout (min)        (START_STOP_TIME) = 10

 WLM dispatcher enabled                 (WLM_DISPATCHER) = NO
 WLM dispatcher concurrency            (WLM_DISP_CONCUR) = COMPUTED
 WLM dispatcher CPU shares enabled (WLM_DISP_CPU_SHARES) = NO
 WLM dispatcher min. utilization (%) (WLM_DISP_MIN_UTIL) = 5

 Communication buffer exit library list (COMM_EXIT_LIST) = 
 Current effective arch level         (CUR_EFF_ARCH_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:5 I:0 SB:0
 Current effective code level         (CUR_EFF_CODE_LVL) = V:10 R:5 M:0 F:5 I:0 SB:0

 Keystore type                           (KEYSTORE_TYPE) = NONE
 Keystore location                   (KEYSTORE_LOCATION) =
```

db.cfg:

```
       Database Configuration for Database STAGE_DB

 Database configuration release level                    = 0x1000
 Database release level                                  = 0x1000

 Database territory                                      = US
 Database code page                                      = 1208
 Database code set                                       = UTF-8
 Database country/region code                            = 1
 Database collating sequence                             = IDENTITY
 Alternate collating sequence              (ALT_COLLATE) = 
 Number compatibility                                    = OFF
 Varchar2 compatibility                                  = OFF
 Date compatibility                                      = OFF
 Database page size                                      = 4096

 Statement concentrator                      (STMT_CONC) = OFF

 Discovery support for this database       (DISCOVER_DB) = ENABLE

 Restrict access                                         = NO
 Default query optimization class         (DFT_QUERYOPT) = 5
 Degree of parallelism                      (DFT_DEGREE) = 1
 Continue upon arithmetic exceptions   (DFT_SQLMATHWARN) = NO
 Default refresh age                   (DFT_REFRESH_AGE) = 0
 Default maintained table types for opt (DFT_MTTB_TYPES) = SYSTEM
 Number of frequent values retained     (NUM_FREQVALUES) = 10
 Number of quantiles retained            (NUM_QUANTILES) = 20

 Decimal floating point rounding mode  (DECFLT_ROUNDING) = ROUND_HALF_EVEN

 Backup pending                                          = NO

 All committed transactions have been written to disk    = NO
 Rollforward pending                                     = NO
 Restore pending                                         = NO

 Multi-page file allocation enabled                      = YES

 Log retain for recovery status                          = RECOVERY
 User exit for logging status                            = NO

 Self tuning memory                    (SELF_TUNING_MEM) = ON
 Size of database shared memory (4KB)  (DATABASE_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(1472088)
 Database memory threshold               (DB_MEM_THRESH) = 10
 Max storage for lock list (4KB)              (LOCKLIST) = AUTOMATIC(273120)
 Percent. of lock lists per application       (MAXLOCKS) = AUTOMATIC(98)
 Package cache size (4KB)                   (PCKCACHESZ) = AUTOMATIC(40438)
 Sort heap thres for shared sorts (4KB) (SHEAPTHRES_SHR) = AUTOMATIC(17010)
 Sort list heap (4KB)                         (SORTHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(3402)

 Database heap (4KB)                            (DBHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(2579)
 Catalog cache size (4KB)              (CATALOGCACHE_SZ) = 4096
 Log buffer size (4KB)                        (LOGBUFSZ) = 98
 Utilities heap size (4KB)                (UTIL_HEAP_SZ) = 56710
 SQL statement heap (4KB)                     (STMTHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(8192)
 Default application heap (4KB)             (APPLHEAPSZ) = AUTOMATIC(256)
 Application Memory Size (4KB)             (APPL_MEMORY) = AUTOMATIC(40016)
 Statistics heap size (4KB)               (STAT_HEAP_SZ) = AUTOMATIC(4384)

 Interval for checking deadlock (ms)         (DLCHKTIME) = 10000
 Lock timeout (sec)                        (LOCKTIMEOUT) = 45

 Changed pages threshold                (CHNGPGS_THRESH) = 80
 Number of asynchronous page cleaners   (NUM_IOCLEANERS) = AUTOMATIC(2)
 Number of I/O servers                   (NUM_IOSERVERS) = AUTOMATIC(16)
 Sequential detect flag                      (SEQDETECT) = YES
 Default prefetch size (pages)         (DFT_PREFETCH_SZ) = AUTOMATIC

 Track modified pages                         (TRACKMOD) = NO

 Default number of containers                            = 1
 Default tablespace extentsize (pages)   (DFT_EXTENT_SZ) = 32

 Max number of active applications            (MAXAPPLS) = AUTOMATIC(57)
 Average number of active applications       (AVG_APPLS) = AUTOMATIC(1)
 Max DB files open per application            (MAXFILOP) = 61440

 Log file size (4KB)                         (LOGFILSIZ) = 128000
 Number of primary log files                (LOGPRIMARY) = 12
 Number of secondary log files               (LOGSECOND) = 10
 Changed path to log files                  (NEWLOGPATH) = 
 Path to log files                                       = /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/LOGSTREAM0000/
 Overflow log path                     (OVERFLOWLOGPATH) = 
 Mirror log path                         (MIRRORLOGPATH) = 
 First active log file                                   = S0000897.LOG
 Block log on disk full                (BLK_LOG_DSK_FUL) = NO
 Block non logged operations            (BLOCKNONLOGGED) = NO
 Percent max primary log space by transaction  (MAX_LOG) = 0
 Num. of active log files for 1 active UOW(NUM_LOG_SPAN) = 0

 Percent log file reclaimed before soft chckpt (SOFTMAX) = 520
 Target for oldest page in LBP       (PAGE_AGE_TRGT_MCR) = 240

 HADR database role                                      = STANDARD
 HADR local host name                  (HADR_LOCAL_HOST) = 
 HADR local service name                (HADR_LOCAL_SVC) = 
 HADR remote host name                (HADR_REMOTE_HOST) = 
 HADR remote service name              (HADR_REMOTE_SVC) = 
 HADR instance name of remote server  (HADR_REMOTE_INST) = 
 HADR timeout value                       (HADR_TIMEOUT) = 120
 HADR target list                     (HADR_TARGET_LIST) = 
 HADR log write synchronization mode     (HADR_SYNCMODE) = NEARSYNC
 HADR spool log data limit (4KB)      (HADR_SPOOL_LIMIT) = 0
 HADR log replay delay (seconds)     (HADR_REPLAY_DELAY) = 0
 HADR peer window duration (seconds)  (HADR_PEER_WINDOW) = 0

 First log archive method                 (LOGARCHMETH1) = LOGRETAIN
 Archive compression for logarchmeth1    (LOGARCHCOMPR1) = OFF
 Options for logarchmeth1                  (LOGARCHOPT1) = 
 Second log archive method                (LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF
 Archive compression for logarchmeth2    (LOGARCHCOMPR2) = OFF
 Options for logarchmeth2                  (LOGARCHOPT2) = 
 Failover log archive path                (FAILARCHPATH) = 
 Number of log archive retries on error   (NUMARCHRETRY) = 5
 Log archive retry Delay (secs)         (ARCHRETRYDELAY) = 20
 Vendor options                              (VENDOROPT) = 

 Auto restart enabled                      (AUTORESTART) = ON
 Index re-creation time and redo index build  (INDEXREC) = RESTART
 Log pages during index build            (LOGINDEXBUILD) = OFF
 Default number of loadrec sessions    (DFT_LOADREC_SES) = 1
 Number of database backups to retain   (NUM_DB_BACKUPS) = 12
 Recovery history retention (days)     (REC_HIS_RETENTN) = 366
 Auto deletion of recovery objects    (AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ) = OFF

 TSM management class                    (TSM_MGMTCLASS) = 
 TSM node name                            (TSM_NODENAME) = 
 TSM owner                                   (TSM_OWNER) = 
 TSM password                             (TSM_PASSWORD) = 

 Automatic maintenance                      (AUTO_MAINT) = ON
   Automatic database backup            (AUTO_DB_BACKUP) = ON
   Automatic table maintenance          (AUTO_TBL_MAINT) = ON
     Automatic runstats                  (AUTO_RUNSTATS) = ON
       Real-time statistics            (AUTO_STMT_STATS) = OFF
       Statistical views              (AUTO_STATS_VIEWS) = OFF
       Automatic sampling                (AUTO_SAMPLING) = OFF
     Automatic reorganization               (AUTO_REORG) = ON

 Auto-Revalidation                          (AUTO_REVAL) = DISABLED

 Currently Committed                        (CUR_COMMIT) = DISABLED
 CHAR output with DECIMAL input        (DEC_TO_CHAR_FMT) = V95
 Enable XML Character operations        (ENABLE_XMLCHAR) = YES
 WLM Collection Interval (minutes)     (WLM_COLLECT_INT) = 0
 Monitor Collect Settings
 Request metrics                       (MON_REQ_METRICS) = NONE
 Activity metrics                      (MON_ACT_METRICS) = NONE
 Object metrics                        (MON_OBJ_METRICS) = NONE
 Routine data                             (MON_RTN_DATA) = NONE
   Routine executable list            (MON_RTN_EXECLIST) = OFF
 Unit of work events                      (MON_UOW_DATA) = NONE
   UOW events with package list        (MON_UOW_PKGLIST) = OFF
   UOW events with executable list    (MON_UOW_EXECLIST) = OFF
 Lock timeout events                   (MON_LOCKTIMEOUT) = NONE
 Deadlock events                          (MON_DEADLOCK) = WITHOUT_HIST
 Lock wait events                         (MON_LOCKWAIT) = NONE
 Lock wait event threshold               (MON_LW_THRESH) = 4294967295
 Number of package list entries         (MON_PKGLIST_SZ) = 32
 Lock event notification level         (MON_LCK_MSG_LVL) = 1

 SMTP Server                               (SMTP_SERVER) = 
 SQL conditional compilation flags         (SQL_CCFLAGS) = 
 Section actuals setting               (SECTION_ACTUALS) = NONE
 Connect procedure                        (CONNECT_PROC) = 
 Adjust temporal SYSTEM_TIME period (SYSTIME_PERIOD_ADJ) = NO
 Log DDL Statements                      (LOG_DDL_STMTS) = NO
 Log Application Information             (LOG_APPL_INFO) = NO
 Default data capture on new Schemas   (DFT_SCHEMAS_DCC) = NO
 Default table organization              (DFT_TABLE_ORG) = ROW
 Default string units                     (STRING_UNITS) = SYSTEM
 National character string mapping       (NCHAR_MAPPING) = GRAPHIC_CU16
 Database is in write suspend state                      = NO
 Extended row size support             (EXTENDED_ROW_SZ) = DISABLE
 Encryption Library for Backup                 (ENCRLIB) = 
 Encryption Options for Backup                (ENCROPTS) = 
 Encrypted database                                      = NO
```

alert.cfg http://pastebin.com/AjPXD9mF

Comment: And both have DB2 installed as root? and appropriate permissions? And both have logging switched to something other than circular? (although personally I'd go with DISK over LOGRETAIN, allows you AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ to automatically prune logs along with backups then).

Comment: @ChrisAldrich all yes.

Comment: I should at least receive "Backup in progress" notifications when I do a manual backup, right? That doesn't happen either

Comment: You need to use db2 list utilities [show detail] in order to see if there is a backup in progress or not. (The show detail is optional.)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is (your config all looks fine to me) but if you've got a working server my first suggestion would be to simply dump all the config on both machines to some text files and diff them to see if you've missed anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was buggy semaphores in RHEL. Strangely, running `gstack` on frozen process helped to unfreeze it.

```
# workaround for http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21694920
echo 'gstack `pgrep -f ^db2acd` >/dev/null 2>&1' >/etc/cron.hourly/db2acd-wdog.cron
chmod 755 /etc/cron.hourly/db2acd-wdog.cron
```

Answer (score 2):

Has your database been explicitly activated (with `ACTIVATE DATABASE`)?  DB2 will not evaluate whether a database is a candidate for automatic backups if it is not active.

Relying on having at least 1 connection to the database to keep the database activated is a recipe for pain.

That said, I moved away from relying on automatic backups a long time ago, instead relying on the consistency and control you get when using a scheduler like `cron`.

Comment: `ACTIVATE DATABASE` Tried that, didn't help. `I moved away from relying on automatic backups`. Had to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently in the same situation, just solved now by replacing data-studio generated

```
BackupCriteria 
numberOfFullBackups="1"
timeSinceLastBackup="24" 
logSpaceConsumedSinceLastBackup="6400"
```

by

```
BackupCriteria 
numberOfFullBackups="1"
timeSinceLastBackup="22" 
logSpaceConsumedSinceLastBackup="1"
```

If you want to keep a small number of backups, do not forget to set rec_his_retentn to 0

Lastly, check authorizations.